# Passing arrays with values returned from another user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 functions in question:

```
' Starting from first row, navigate through headers (rows) in lookup_range and return cell value at row_index if we reach a single column Range at the end of navigation; N/A otherwise.
Public Function HLOOKUPRANGE(headers() As Variant, lookup_range As range, row_index As Integer) As Variant
' returns the minimum value in search range that is greater than or equal to target.
Public Function MINGE(search As range, target As Variant) As Variant
```

In my excel worksheet, the HLOOKUPRANGE works like this:

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE({"Color", "Red", "Alpha", 50}, A1:Z30, SELECTED_INDEX)
=HLOOKUPRANGE({"Color", "Blue", "Alpha", 100}, A1:Z30, SELECTED_INDEX)
```

But how can I make it work with another function, like this?:

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE({"Color", "Red", "Alpha", MINGE(A4:Z4, INPUT_ALPHA_VALUE)}, A1:Z:30, SELECTED_INDEX)
```

Excel is not letting me put MINGE between {} and I think the problem is with passing arrays in this manner. What can I do to pass the result of MINGE into HLOOKUPRANGE?

Tip: MINGE is "MINimum Greater than or Equal"

Comment: No, it's not because of passing arrays in this manner. It's because [array constants](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx) fundamentally only accept constants.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking along those lines as well. Only constants allowed. Thanks for the link to full documentation. Is there a non-constant array though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways that I can think of...

**WAY 1**

Write a 3rd function which will unite the Array with the MINGE value. I have created a sample since I don't know what HLOOKUPRANGE and MINGE does but the concept is the same.

The SID() imitates HLOOKUPRANGE in this example. But all it does at the moment is it sums the values

So if you enter

```
=SID({1,2,3,4,5})
```

it will give you the sum 15. Now lets say we wanted the sum of

```
=SID({1,2,3,4,5,MINGE()})
```

where the value of MINGE() is 6. This is how we would do it

```
=SID(Unite({1,2,3,4,5},6))
```

Which will give you 21. This code goes in a module

```
Option Explicit

Dim TempAr() As Variant

Public Function Sid(headers() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim temp As Long, i As Long
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        temp = temp + headers(i)
    Next i
    Sid = temp
End Function

Public Function Unite(MyArray() As Variant, Vl As Variant) As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    n = UBound(MyArray)

    ReDim Preserve TempAr(n + 1)

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        TempAr(i) = MyArray(i)
    Next i

    TempAr(n + 1) = Vl
    Unite = TempAr
End Function
```

If I were to apply the same to your functions then it would look something like this

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE(UNITE({"Color", "Red", "Alpha"},MINGE(A4:Z4, INPUT_ALPHA_VALUE)), A1:Z30, SELECTED_INDEX)
```

**WAY 2**

You could change HLOOKUPRANGE function slightly to accept optional values. For example the formula

=SUM({1,2,3,4,5},{6}) does the same thing as above in a worksheet.

So you could change your HLOOKUPRANGE() to

```
Public Function HLOOKUPRANGE(headers() As Variant, lookup_range As Range, _
row_index As Integer, Optional HeadersItem1 As Variant, _
Optional HeadersItem2 As Variant) As Variant
    '~~> In the code add HeadersItem1 and HeadersItem2 to headers()
    '~~> If they are not blank
End Function
```

USAGE would be like this

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE({"Color", "Red", "Alpha"}, A1:Z30, SELECTED_INDEX,MINGE(A4:Z4, INPUT_ALPHA_VALUE)))
```

or

```
=HLOOKUPRANGE({"Color", "Red"}, A1:Z30, SELECTED_INDEX,MINGE(A4:Z4, INPUT_ALPHA_VALUE)),SELECTED_INDEX,MINGE(B4:B4, INPUT_ALPHA_VALUE)))
```

Comment: Following your idea of Optional parameter, do you suppose I can use ParamArray for headers? My HLOOKUPRANGE is recursive. On each recursion, I remove the first item in headers(). But I am stuck at removing items from a ParamArray and then supplying to the recursion call. Any tips for me regarding this?

Comment: @Jake: I wouldn't suggest ParamArray in your case then as AFAIK, Erase or ReDim can't be performed on the ParamArray.

Comment: But I noticed
`public function MakeArray(ParamArray values() as Variant) as Variant()
MakeArray = values
end function`
 worked just as fine.